# Django circular import error, trying to allow location to access activity

Tags: python, django

ImportError: cannot import name 'Activity' from partially initialized module 'vacaplusapi.models.activity' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/name/project/server/projectname/models/activity.py)

models/activity.py

```
from django.db import models  
from .activity import Activity

class Activity(models.Model):

    activity = models.OneToOneField(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    date = models.DateField(default="0000-00-00",)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
```

models/location.py

- from vacaplusapi.models import Activity
- from vacaplusapi.models.vacauser import VacaUser
- from django.db import models
- from .vacauser import VacaUser

class Location(models.Model):

```
time = models.DateField(models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True))
activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="activity")
user = models.ForeignKey(VacaUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="vacauser")
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
```

Comment: What is `from .activity import Activity` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can not import something from the same module, since at that time, the module is loading. You do not need to anyway. You can make use of the `'self'` string literal to refer to the same model, so:

```
from django.db import models  

class Activity(models.Model):
    activity = models.OneToOneField(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='activity_reverse'
    )
    # …
```

It is however not clear to me why you are referring to an `Activity` from an `Activity` with a `OneToOneField`.